# i get value error in model.fit(x_train,y_train) why? and what is the solution please?

Tags: scikit-learn, training-data, data-fitting

```
model_1 = SGDClassifier(random_state = 0)
model_2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 0)
model_3 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 2)

for model in (model_1, model_2, model_3):
    #x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print(mode.__class__.__name, model.score(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: Can you include more details regrading to your issue? Please format the code if possible and include details like in which line the error occurs and appreciate if you could include the original error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.